# CASE WITH MULTIPLE SELECT STATEMENTS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm trying to put a select statement within a case but I'm unable to put it properly.

The first case statement is fine, but the second one is the problem.

Can somebody guide me please with the correct syntax,

```
select u.unit_id,
       u.order_code,
       u.order_item,
       u.roll_sheet,
       u.date_wound,
       u.date_shipped,
       u.unit_status,
       u.warehouse_code,
       (case
         when u.unit_id_turnup is not null then
          (select u1.onput_id
             from unit u1
            where u.unit_id_turnup = u1.unit_id)
         else
          u.onput_id
       end) "onput id",
       
       (case
         when u.unit_id_turnup is not null then
          (select CASE WHEN U1.UNIT_ID_TURNUP IS NOT NULL
             from unit u1 then (select u3.onput_id
                                  from unit u3
                                 where u1.unit_id_turnup = u3.unit_id) else u1.onput_id)
         else
          u.onput_id
       end) "onput id2",
  from unit u
```

Comment: Your `case when` statement is malformed on your second query (`CASE WHEN {} ELSE {} END`) and you have some `FROM` in the middle. Your query could be better solved using `left join`.

Comment: Can you guide a little, how @jamieDrq

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would all help.  Also, explain the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can speculate that the code that you intend is:

```
select . . . ,
       coalesce(u1.onput_id, u.onput_id) as onput_id,
       coalesce(u2.onput_id, u1.onput_id, u.onput_id) as onput_id2
from unit u left join
     unit u1
     on u.unit_id_turnup = u1.id left join
     unit u2
     on u1.unit_id_turnup = u2.id
```

Without sample data and a clear explanation, this is really just a guess.  However, this appears to be what you are attempting.

Comment: It worked as I needed, thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff